# POST array only populating when key has value

Tags: php, html, post

This is a weird one for me. But after upgrading to php 5.6.1, I noticed that POST arrays weren't populating properly.
With this code:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="username" />
<input type="submit" value="click">
</form>
```

If I just click submit, I get an empty array.
BUT if I fill in the text input (ie. John Doe). The array shows up as it should.
I checked the raw POST data:

```
$raw_post = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

and it IS being sent (even when empty), but it's just not showing up in the array. Ie:

```
Array ( )
```

I'm not even sure if this is related to the upgrade, but I did just notice it after ugrading.

Comment: What does `$_POST` look like?

Comment: On my localhost it shows:
`array(username=>)`
On my server it shows:
`array()`

Comment: What does var_dump($_POST) show?

Comment: var_dump shows:
`array(0) { }`

Comment: Are localhost and server the same version?

Comment: Yep. both are php 5.6.1

Comment: What is the server daemon? Could it be interfering with the request and omitting blank inputs?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define   `value=""`  in each input

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="username" value=""/>
    <input type="submit" value="click">
    </form>
```

Comment: You should have to.
If you don't define it, it should show up as:
`Array( username=> )`
It does so on my localhost, but not on my server.